# Making changes in array data efficient

Tags: php, arrays

I have this 3 insertion to database via function call. This code is working no problem.

```
                    //* Set the function parameters.
                    $client_id = $_SESSION['user']['client_id'];

                    $params = array(
                            'name' => 'Abu',
                            'data' => 'user',
                            'active' => 'y',
                            'stamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            );

                    $id = $client->user_add($client_id, $params);                           

                    $params = array(
                            'name' => 'Ali',
                            'data' => 'user',
                            'active' => 'y',
                            'stamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            );

                    $id = $client->user_add($client_id, $params);           

                    $params = array(
                            'name' => 'Siti',
                            'data' => 'user',
                            'active' => 'y',
                            'stamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            );

                    $id = $client->user_add($client_id, $params);
```

The difference is only in `name`. Is there anyway I could make only one function call to insert data? With loop or something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the names in an array and loop over it. You put inside the loop the exact code you repeated 3 times, except you use the loop variable instead of a string as name array item.

```
$names = array('Abu', 'Ali', 'Siti');

foreach($names as $name) {
    $params = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'data' => 'user',
        'active' => 'y',
        'stamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );

    $id = $client->user_add($client_id, $params);  
}
```